# MySQL - group by on groupped result

Tags: mysql, group-by

Not sure how to best title the question.

I have a table that records player's wins. I need to query for how many players have how many wins.

Here's an example DB: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gCEKmtPQr7nvhiZDyexn9C/0
Here's the expected result:

```
wins, players_count
1, 1
2, 3
```

And I'm a bit lost. I can get number of wins per player easily (group by user_id, where status='win' and select count on it), but how do I group those results into my expected result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You will need to use two-level Select queries with `Group By`. A sub-select query is also called as [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).
- In the inner select query, get total wins per user.
- Now, in the outer select, `Group By` on the total wins, and count the users for them.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  dt.total_wins AS wins, 
  COUNT(*) AS players_count 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    user_id, 
    COUNT(*) AS total_wins 
  FROM a 
  WHERE status = 'win' 
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS dt 
GROUP BY dt.total_wins
```

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE a (status VARCHAR(255), user_id int);

INSERT INTO a (status, user_id)
VALUES ('win', 1),
('win', 2),
('win', 3),
('win', 2),
('win', 4),
('win', 4),
('win', 1),
('not win', 1);
```

---

**Query Result**

```
| wins | players_count |
| ---- | ------------- |
| 1    | 1             |
| 2    | 3             |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gCEKmtPQr7nvhiZDyexn9C/2)

Comment: I do believe this is it, let me just adapt for my actual project and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @devk happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Example without `CASE` Statements:

After you got your `wins_per_user` simply count the `user_ids`, and group by `wincount` again:

```
SELECT
  wincount AS WinCount, count(user_id) as UserCount
FROM
  (SELECT 
   count(*) as wincount, user_id
  FROM a 
    where status='win'
  GROUP BY user_id) as wins_per_user
GROUP BY wincount
```

Results in

```
WinCount UserCount
1        1
2        3
```